# Excel VBA Macros Using Checkboxes To Hide Rows - If Else Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, checkbox, case

I have 60 check boxes on one worksheet. They are form control checkboxes. They all do a similar function which is hide rows. When you click the check box it shows the rows
When unchecked the rows are hidden. Is there an easy if else or case statement I could write for this:

```vb
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Range("B4").Value = True Then
        Rows("5:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("5:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    If Range("B63").Value = True Then
        Rows("64:102").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("64:102").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox3_Click()

    If Range("B103").Value = True Then
        Rows("104:129").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("104:129").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox4_Click()

    If Range("B130").Value = True Then
        Rows("131:160").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("131:160").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox5_Click()

    If Range("B161").Value = True Then
        Rows("162:183").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("162:183").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox6_Click()

    If Range("B184").Value = True Then
        Rows("185:222").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("185:222").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub CheckBox7_Click()

    If Range("B223").Value = True Then
        Rows("224:244").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("224:244").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

........etc etc

**Also,** if I need to add more rows in or delete rows, how would I code that in?

I would appreciate a format that I could use to create my own check boxes in the future without having to manually fix and edit them individually

Comment: Are you up for working with named ranges instead?

Comment: hi sure, if it will do the job. I know how to do a named range and use one active x checkbox to hide a  set of rows. I have about 60 checkboxes, so how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   HideRows "B63", "64:102"
End Sub


Sub HideRows(controllerRange, rowRange)
   Rows(rowRange).EntireRow.Hidden = Not Range(controllerRange).Value
End Sub
```

You could also call HideRows directly from the checkbox.

In CheckBox1 assign macro, you would enter the following:

```
'HideRows "B63","64:102"'
```

Note: The single quotes MUST be entered as shown.

Comment: Hi, would that be one macro  for all 60 checkboxes? Or the same code I have to duplicate again?

Comment: HideRows is one macro, but the custom range has to be set in each click action.  You might be able to avoid this if the ranges are names and you triggered an on change event but I personally like @grantnz solution better.

Comment: I think I understand, So I need to create named ranges and then I use one macro to assign to all the different check boxes, where do I put the custom ranges?

Comment: I assumed you were already using a "Cell Link" (under the Control tab in Format Control" to specify a cell in the spreadsheet that is updated with the current checkbox value (in the example above B63).  The only additional thing to do is to use "Assign Macro" to also specify this linked cell and the row range that the checkbox controls.  That is, assign 'HideRows "B63","64:102"' as the macro (including all the quotes).

Comment: This seem to give good grounds to get what i want. Thank you.